# LINQ query syntax to method syntax

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity

I use asp.net, c# and EF4.

I'm puzzled by this LINQ query:

```
  var queryContents = from a in context.CmsContentsAssignedToes
                    where a.UserId == myUserGuid
                    join cnt in context.CmsContents
                    on a.ContentId equals cnt.ContentId
                    where cnt.TypeContent == myTypeContent & cnt.ModeContent == myModeContent
                    select cnt;
```

I would like write its equivalent in **LINQ method syntax** to retrieve CmsContents.

In my conceptual model are two entity types:

- CmsContent
- CmsContentsAssignedTo

and their entity sets:

- CmsContents
- CmsContentsAssignedToes

and navigation properties:

- in CmsContent -->  CmsContentsAssignedTo RETURN: --> Instance of CmsContentsAssignedTo
- in CmsContentsAssignedTo -->  CmsContent RETURN: --> Instance of CmsContent

Do you know how to do it? I tried for more that one day but I cannot solve it!

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The equivalent method syntax is:

```
 var queryContents = context.CmsContentsAssignedToes
                            .Where(a => a.UserId == myUserGuid)
                            .Join(context.CmsContents,
                                  a => a.ContentId,
                                  cnt => cnt.ContentId,
                                  (a, cnt) = new { a, cnt })
                            .Where(z => z.cnt.TypeContent == myTypeContent &
                                        z.cnt.ModeContent == myModeContent)
                            .Select(z => z.cnt);
```

See my [Edulinq blog post on query expressions](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/28/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-41-how-query-expressions-work.aspx) for more details of how this works, and particularly where the "z" comes from (it's not really called "z"; it doesn't have a name as it's a *transparent identifier*).

Comment: Thanks Jon for you explanation and link. Have a nice day!

Comment: Hi, I posted a question, I would like you expert opinion if you have time. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260346/linq-understading-non-equijoins thanks in advance for your help.