# LINQ understading Non-Equijoins

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I use asp.net 4, ef 4 and c#, LINQ and Non-Equijoins.

Here below I wrote two examples of Non-Equijoins.
Both are working fine in my model.

Because I'm pretty new to Linq, I would like ask you:

- Which syntax typology would you advice me to adopt in my code?
- Which code performance faster?

Thanks for your help:

Here some useful links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882533.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310804.aspx

---

```
// Query sintax
var queryContents = 
    from cnt in context.CmsContents
    let cntA =
        from a in context.CmsContentsAssignedToes
        select a.CmsContent.ContentId
    where cntA.Contains(cnt.ContentId) == false
    select cnt;

// Query method   
var queryContents02 =
    from c in context.CmsContents
    where !(
        from a in context.CmsContentsAssignedToes 
        select a.ContentId).Contains(c.ContentId)
    select c;
```

Comment: To find out which one performs faster, you can use the Query Profiler to find out which queries are executed and how they perform. Normally you should pick the query that is the most readable, and only if performance is a problem try to change it (or add indexes).

Comment: do you think a Stopwatch would be reliable to measure my CLR? I made some text and Query method seems performance faster

Comment: You should look at the actual logical reads of a query and the execution plan. Those can predict how queries will perform in the future.

Comment: Thanks Steven for your answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd prompt for a third option:

```
var validContentIds = from a in context.CmsContentsAssignedToes 
                      select a.ContentId;

var queryContents = from cnt in context.CmsContents
                    where !validContentIds.Contains(cnt.ContentId)
                    select cnt;
```

Or alternatively (and equivalently):

```
var validIds = context.CmsContentsAssignedToes.Select(a => a.ContentId);

var queryContents = context.CmsContents
                           .Where(cnt => !validIds.Contains(cnt.ContentId));
```

I wouldn't expect the performance to be impacted - I'd expect all of these to end up with the same SQL.

Comment: Thanks Jon to reply my question.. your version is much more readable!

Answer (score 1):

I like the first query syntax (it is better readable for me but this part of question is subjective) and I think the perforamance will be the same because queries are actually the same. `let` keyword just stores subexpression to variable but generated SQL query should be the "same".